# How to get matches from multiple lines using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

```
I ACE | AA33cc55BB44                      |         |            |                I
I     | AAAAAA-BB2CC-4424-1-22            |  11.113 | 10.09.2022 | bCa0111.XAC    I
I     |                                   |         |            |                I
I BAC | Aa315c5cab44                      |         |            |                I
I     | 5564aa-BB2CC-44gd-1-22            |  21.334 | 10.09.2022 | Aba0221.XAC    I
I     |                                   |         |            |                I
I CAC | aacccc54BB44                      |         |            |                I
I     | AAAAAA-BB2CC-aaaa-1-22            |  61.222 | 10.09.2022 | bCa0232.XAC    I
I     |                                   |         |            |                I
I DAC | ii2ii2ii2664                      |         |            |                I
I     | BBBBBB-BB2CC-4424-1-22            |  81.888 | 10.09.2022 | Aba0243.XAC    I
```

I have used this pattern:
`\| (.*)            \|  \d{2}\.\d{3} \| \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4} \| (.*)    \I`

Attributes that I want to grab:

Group I:

```
AA33cc55BB44                      
AAAAAA-BB2CC-4424-1-22
bCa0111.XAC
```

Group II:

```
Aa315c5cab44
5564aa-BB2CC-44gd-1-22 
Aba0221.XAC
```

Group III:

```
aacccc54BB44
AAAAAA-BB2CC-aaaa-1-22
bCa0232.XAC
```

Group IV:

```
ii2ii2ii2664
BBBBBB-BB2CC-4424-1-22
Aba0243.XAC
```

Can anyone help me how I can get only these attributes from this text?

Comment: In [RegexOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-6.0), there is `Multiline`. You can use that along with utilizing [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=net-6.0) to match 2 or 3 lines at a time.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang The question is how to use it ? which would be the pattern to find that match !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?m)^[^|\n]*\|[ \t]*([^\s|]+).*\n[^|\n]*\|[ \t]*(\S+)\s*(?:\|[^|\n]*){2}\|[ \t]*(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtF87i/1). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - `RegexOptions.Multiline` option on
- `^` - start of a line
- `[^|\n]*` - zero or more chars other than a newline and `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `[ \t]*` - zero or more spaces or TABs (you may use `[\p{Zs}\t]*` here to match any Unicode horizontal whitespaces)
- `([^\s|]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and `|`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\n` - a newline char
- `[^|\n]*\|[ \t]*` - zero or more chars other than a newline and `|`, then a `|` char and zero or more spaces or TABs
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\|[^|\n]*){2}` - two sequences of `|` and then zero or more chars other than `|` and whitespace
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `[ \t]*` - zero or more spaces or TABs
- `(\S+)` - Group 3: one or more non-whitespace chars.

In C#:

```cs
var pattern = @"^[^|\n]*\|[ \t]*([^\s|]+).*\n[^|\n]*\|[ \t]*(\S+)\s*(?:\|[^|\n]*){2}\|[ \t]*(\S+)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
for (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- New match ---");
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```